# php $_POST return empty array

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

i thoroughly tried many method on this forum for this topic but i can't solve my problem.

so here's the problem. i can't return my `$_POST` value from the form, but javascript's `document.getElementById().value` can catch the form value.

here's my form code:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <input id="input_date" name="input_date" class="datepicker" placeholder="Choose date" type="text"/>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" value="Submit here" onclick="Submit_date()"/>
</form>
```

this is my php code in the same file:

```
$tanggal = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($_POST['input_date']));
```

this is my javascript code also in the same file:

```
var tanggalan = document.getElementById("input_date").value;
confirm("Date1: " + tanggalan + 
"\n Date2: " + <?php echo json_encode($_POST['input_date'])?> + 
"\n Date3: " + <?php echo json_encode($tanggal)?>);
```

for example, the form is writed `"2 March, 2016"`, the `Date1` returns exactly what i want, but `Date2` returns `"null"` and `Date3` returns `"70707070-0101-0101".`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$_POST` how would u get values untill you submit a form? remove `action='#'` and `enctype="text/plain"`. and change the button type to submit `type="button"` to this `type="submit"`.

Comment: I can't see the Submit_date() function defined, unless form is submitted $_POST is empty. Either submit button needs to be clicked for $_POST to not be empty or JS function needs to submit form automatically on an event say page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"\n Date2: " + <?php echo json_encode($_POST['tanggal'])?>
```

Date2 is null simply because your calling $_POST variable that does not exist.

`$tanggal` is a variable not a $_POST variable as you assigned here

```
$tanggal = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($_POST['input_date']));
```

Make it `$tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'] = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($_POST['input_date']));` to make it work.

Comment: yup sorry for the typo, it should be $_POST['input_date'] but still returns 'null'

Comment: Make sure that variable declaration is there before getting the value of it. And also have you tried what Norman commented in your post? Did you change the `type='button'` to `type='submit'`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove  enctype="text/plain" and add action to the form which helps you setting $_POST when you submit the form.

Also, use the following in the PHP code to avoid returning "70707070-0101-0101"

$tanggal = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['input_date']));

Comment: @Sairam Salim:- Try my edited answer and let me know the result.